# How to initialize variable amount of Django model fields at once?

Tags: python, django

I fetch some data for the Stackexchange user and store it in my Django model:

```
class StackExchangeProfile(models.Model):
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    expires = models.IntegerField()
    reputation = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    link = models.URLField(null=True)
    image = models.URLField(null=True)
    ...
```

I'm instanciating this model with a pair of required parameters:

```
token = {'access_token': 'abcd123abcd123abcd123', 'expires': 1234}
se_profile = StackExchangeProfile(**token)
```

And I've came up with a method to set the non-required ones:

```
class StackExchangeProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    def fill_profile(self, reputation, link, image):
        self.reputation = reputation
        self.link = link
        self.image = image
```

Which I'm not very fond of, as it does not allow me to set custom set of attributes (e.g. reputation and link only in case if the user got no image).

Is there a way to achieve such flexibility?

Comment: There's no reason why you can't put the appropriate logic in `fill_profile()`

Comment: @mattm thanks for the prompt comment. However, I do not need to store the whole dictionary in the DB. Just the specific list of fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same `**kwargs` magic as in the instantiating:

```
def fill_profile(self, **kwargs):
    for attr, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        setattr(self, attr, value)
```

And then call this method with named arguments:

```
se_profile.fill_profile(reputation=1234, link='http://example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea to have a default value for each field so that you wouldn't have to always check if a parameter exists or not.

```
def fill_profile(self, reputation=None, link=None, image=None):
        self.reputation = reputation
        self.link = link
        self.image = image

se_profile.fill_profile(image="http://a.com/a.jpg")
```

Comment: It is a bad idea - `reputation` and `link` fields will be set to `None` regardless of their previous values.

Comment: @catavaran I suppose fill_profile is meant to run once for initialization, so it's better to be sure that all objects have all of the possible attributes some of which may be None. If the purpose of fill_profile were to change some attribute of an object there wouldn't be the need for a function, we could simply assign that attribute: self.reputation = 1